# Having troubles with File.contains(file) and File.add(file)

Tags: android, file

I try to code an Android App.

The code below should add the parent of a file to my list, but only if the parent is not already in the list.

`files[]` is an array of Files in a directory

`imageFolders` is created like this:

```
private List <File> imageFolders;
private String [] extensions;
File [] files = folder.listFiles();
extensions = new String [] {".png",".jpg",".jpeg"};

//important part: 

if(files[i].toString().contains(extensions[b]))
{
    System.out.println("Checkpoint 1");                     
    if(!imageFolders.contains((File)files[i].getParentFile()))
    {  
        System.out.println("Checkpoint 2");
        imageFolders.add((File)files[i].getParentFile());
    }
 }
```

And then the log gives me this and the app shuts down:

```
09-26 08:33:55.580: I/System.out(1753): /system/lib/hw/camera.goldfish.jpeg.so //gives me the file[i]   
09-26 08:33:55.580: I/System.out(1753): Checkpoint 1    
09-26 08:33:55.590: D/AndroidRuntime(1753): Shutting down VM    
09-26 08:33:55.610: W/dalvikvm(1753): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
(group=0xb1a87ba8)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753): Process: de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager, PID: 1753    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager/de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager.Side2}: java.lang.NullPointerException    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
Method)
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager.Side2.hSearchImages(Side2.java:61)   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager.Side2.hSearchImages(Side2.java:52)   
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager.Side2.hSearchImages(Side2.java:52)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at de.FriedSloth.fastphotomanager.Side2.onCreate(Side2.java:32)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)    
09-26 08:33:55.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1753):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: It would be good if you add the essential parts of your code including the part of setting **imageFolders**,

Comment: private List <File> imageFolders;

Comment: files[] is an array of Files in a directory - having the bad feeling that i had to do something like imageFolders = new List(); not near my pc to test it atm.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the elements to your code block. :)

Comment: Im on my phne and thought just commenting would be the fastest way to give you the Information, edited my post now. Thanks for helping an Android and stackoverflow beginner :)

Comment: I can't see your edit and you should take the time to edit your question in the "right" way and add necessary information for other users. However add all needed code to the question that everyone will understand what variables and types you are using.

Comment: Edited it below the Code block i will correct it tomorrow on my pc :) should i also add the whole method and the log ?

Comment: All information to understand you problem are good, but don't post the complete class only the required parts.

Comment: "my app stops running at this point" Do you get "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped"? If so, please post the stack trace. If not, how do you know your app stops running?

Comment: Please change the subject of your post. You have troubles with List.contains().

Comment: Okay tried to make everything clear !